# How to install node.js on Synology Diskstation DS713+

Tags: linux, node.js, gcc, synology

Does anybody know a way to install node.js on **ds713+** (intel atom cpu) ?
I tried some tutorial, all written for diskstations with arm processors and old node-branches.
When i try to build it i the compiler allways stops with:

> /opt/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.2.1/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[1]: *** [/root/node/out/Release/node] Error 1
>
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/node/out'
>
>   make: *** [node] Error 2

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered it by myself. 
If you got same problem use ubuntu 32bit to 
cross-compile with http://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc

Answer (score 2):

There's now a direct download of the Node.js package from SynoCommunity. Instructions are [here](https://synocommunity.com).

Github repo of the binaries is [here](https://github.com/achesco/synology-nodejs-bin)

I haven't found a good tutorial on using it yet, but I've read that the commands are in /volume1/@appstore/node/bin